# Weird issue with CSRF token on custom post action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For a couple of months now I've been using an action called `update_snapshot` in my controller.
Essentially this action tells the server to connect to a webcam and capture/save a jpeg from it that someone uses to visually review a remote location is fully operating as expected.

But anyhow...
Today I started seeing `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` in my logs and the user get's logged out

Now I understand that you need to send a CSRF token with a request, but the issue here is that I am.
This is definitely a brand new issue that happened today and I'm not sure why it's suddenly an issue.

In order to resolve the issue for now I am skipping the before_filter for `:verify_authenticity_token` for this action (and only this action).
I think I can keep it like this without any real issue, but any idea as to why it would suddenly start happening, and why only on this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue here.
I'd somewhat recently added action caching for my show action.
The link that does the post is in this cached view.

The CSRF meta-tag needs to be updated by making a separate ajax request to another, uncached controller that just serves this tag.